# How do I get an event from one parent component to a child-component in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get an event that is fired relatively on the top of the dom-hierarchy to a child component further down the hierarchy.The child is not a direct child of the parent

I understand that I do that with the input-decorator. Please note doing it the other way around like it should be is not possible.

The html of the parent looks like this

```
<element [data]="viewData" (anext)=OnNext($event)></element>
```

I need to get the `$event` available in the child. How do I achieve this?

Comment: For unrelated component use angular service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service with an rxjs Subject, as shown in the psuedo code below.

```
//Evservice.ts

public subject = new Subject();
OnNext(event) {
   subject.next(event)
}

//childComponent.ts
constructor(ser: Evservice)

ser.subject.subscribe((ev) => {//access your event here});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions for this:

- an angular service (injected in both parent and child) with a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` handling the events
- creating a `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` in the parent and passing it to the child via an `@Input()` parameter and subscribing to it in the child
- setting different values into an `@Input()` parameter that is then handled in the child component via an `OnChanges` implementation
  These are the ones I can think of currently.